# Storing broken numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I have a database where I would like to save for example: 10.54 as a float or double.

I have a table with a column named temperature, but the issue is that even though my insert statements goes well, when I query the table, it always returns an integer number, in the example above 10.

These are the tables and statements. Can you please help?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_facts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `network_asset_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `temperature` double(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Possible query:

```
INSERT INTO data_facts (network_asset_code, temperature) VALUES ('abc', 10.5)
```

One query:

```
mysql> select * from data_facts where data_facts.id=1;
+----+--------------------+-------------+
| id | network_asset_code | temperature |
+----+--------------------+-------------+
|  1 | abc                |          10 |
+----+--------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you format temperature,  use  double(255,2) if you want 2 decimal

```
CREATE TABLE `data_facts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `network_asset_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `temperature` double(255,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change temperature datatype to double(255,2)

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using `DECIMAL` instead of `DOUBLE` refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html).
How many digits you can accommodate in `DECIMAL` refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)